# How do I take sql results and populate labels in my header?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am attempting to change my code.  I am in the process of learning while I code and many parts of my C#/ASP.Net application use LINQ to SQL and many parts use commands to directly access the sql database.  I felt like I should standardize these, so I am changing over the LINQ to SQL code.  I have a portion of the code that takes the finds one record based on a session variable and then populates the labels in my header with the sql query results.  here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pinNum = MySession.Current.focusParcel;

    if (pinNum != 0)
    {
        String sql = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Recorder"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sql);
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select PARCEL, PIN_TXT, Owner, Address1, Address2, CSZ, ACRES, LEGAL, Active FROM[ParcelView] WHERE PARCEL = " + pinNum, connection);

        SqlDataReader selectedParcel = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (selectedParcel != null)
        {
            lblPIN_Num.Text = selectedParcel["PARCEL"].ToString();
            lblPIN_TXT.Text = selectedParcel["PIN_TXT"].ToString();
            lblDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
            lblOwner.Text = selectedParcel["Owner"].ToString();
            lblAddress1.Text = selectedParcel["Address1"].ToString();
            lblAddress2.Text = selectedParcel["Address2"].ToString();
            lblCSZ.Text = selectedParcel["CSZ"].ToString();
            lblAcres.Text = string.Format("{0} Acres", selectedParcel["ACRES"]);
            lblLegal.Text = selectedParcel["LEGAL"].ToString();
            if (selectedParcel["Active"].ToString() == "A")
            {
                lblInactive.Text = " (ACTIVE)";
            }
            else
            {
                lblInactive.Text = " (INACTIVE)";
                lnkAddDocument.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        lblCurrentUser.Text = Page.User.Identity.Name;
        connection.Close();
    }
    else
        Response.Redirect("./ParcelSearch.aspx");
}
```

I am receiving the following error:

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

I know the SQL statement used will return a record when it is used directly into sql query of database.

Thanks in advance for any advice.  Should I be concerned about the lack of consistency in accessing data across the application at all?  If so, should I be converting everything to LINQ?  Or converting everything away from LINQ?  I klnow of the existence of MVC and know I should learn it and use it, but I am too far down the path to try to convert there right now.

Comment: no space after FROM `FROM[ParcelView]`.  Is it a copy / paste issue in question or an issue in your code too?

Comment: you have to read a record in the data reader before you can start pulling data. Its a forward only cursor that starts off not pointing to a record. the Read() method advances the reader by 1 and returns true/false if it was successful. So wrap your statement with `if(selectedParcel.Read())`

Comment: First, check your reader's HasRows property to make sure it has data before trying to read field values. Second, consistency will promote ease of maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (selectedParcel != null)
```

To

```
if (selectedParcel.Read())
```

You have to read a record in the data reader before you can start pulling data. Its a forward only cursor that starts off not pointing to a record. The `Read()` method advances the reader by 1 and returns true/false if it was successful.

Note that it is not necessary to call `HasRows` if use the code above. The if block will only be entered if there is a row, if there is not then Read returns false and the block is not entered.

---

#### Edit

There are many bad practices in your code.

1. Use parameterized sql!! This is the most important thing you can take away here!
2. Wrap your connections in using blocks to ensure the connection is ALWAYS closed.

Sql code changes

```
String sql = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Recorder"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sql))
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select PARCEL, PIN_TXT, Owner, Address1, Address2, CSZ, ACRES, LEGAL, Active FROM [ParcelView] WHERE PARCEL = @pinNum", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pinNum", SqlDbType.VarChar){Value = pinNum});
    connection.Open();
    using(SqlDataReader selectedParcel = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (selectedParcel.Read())
        {
            /*code unchanged*/
        }
    }
    /* 1 line code unchanged*/
}
```

Comment: The SqlCommand object also implements `IDisposable` so should be in a `using` block too.

Comment: @GarethD - strik that, I usually do not do it but let me check the actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks so very much for this.  I changed the code like you suggested and it works great.  I am very new to coding in general, and especially to data access, but I feel like I am making strides every day.  This will help me in changing the rest of my LINQ to SQL over.

Comment: @GarethD - seems to cleanup associated events, a site container, and null out the cached metadata. I guess its good practice just so it does not have to stick around for another GC generation.

Comment: @MattSyvertson - glad it helps!

Comment: @MattSyvertson - one more note. I guessed at the type that `pinNum` is, if its a number then change `SqlDbType.VarChar` to the correct type like `SqlDbType.Int`. Try to always use native types and never a string representation (this is true for everything from numbers, dates, etc) unless it is actually a string. This is also true for the persisted type in the table/schema.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have executed the command you need to actually read the data :

```
 SqlDataReader selectedParcel = command.ExecuteReader();
 if (selectedParcel.HasRows)
 {
     selectedParcel.Read();
     ....
     ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `Read()` the `SqlDataReader`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pinNum = MySession.Current.focusParcel;

    if (pinNum == 0)
       Response.Redirect("./ParcelSearch.aspx");

    String sql = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Recorder"].ConnectionString;

    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sql))
    {
       connection.Open();

       SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select PARCEL, PIN_TXT, Owner, Address1, Address2, CSZ, ACRES, LEGAL, Active FROM[ParcelView] WHERE PARCEL =@PinNum ", connection);

       //protect from sql injection
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@PinNum, pinNum);

       using(SqlDataReader selectedParcel = command.ExecuteReader())
       {

           if(!selectedParcel.HasRows)
               return;

           SetLabels(selectedParcel);      
        }    
     }

 }

 private void SetLabels(SqlDataReader selectedParcel)
 {
     lblPIN_Num.Text = selectedParcel["PARCEL"].ToString();
     lblPIN_TXT.Text = selectedParcel["PIN_TXT"].ToString();
     lblDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
     lblOwner.Text = selectedParcel["Owner"].ToString();
     lblAddress1.Text = selectedParcel["Address1"].ToString();
     lblAddress2.Text = selectedParcel["Address2"].ToString();
     lblCSZ.Text = selectedParcel["CSZ"].ToString();
     lblAcres.Text = string.Format("{0} Acres", selectedParcel["ACRES"]);
     lblLegal.Text = selectedParcel["LEGAL"].ToString();

     if (selectedParcel["Active"].ToString() == "A")
     {
         lblInactive.Text = " (ACTIVE)";
     }
     else
     {
         lblInactive.Text = " (INACTIVE)";
         lnkAddDocument.Visible = false;
     }

     lblCurrentUser.Text = Page.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

I refactor your code to look a little bit. You had different problems as not closing your Reader. You was open to sql injection, also you should transfer the connection to Db in separate class.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use this format for your sqlDatareader instead, as it it will parse whether results have been retrieved or not, and will automatically dispose itself on exception:

```
using(SqlDataReader selectedParcel = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (selectedParcel .Read())
    {
        //Assign label text to results
    }
}
```